# References for Bayesian group-Lasso for probit/logit regression

Tags: bayesian, references, lasso, probit, hierarchical-bayesian

Does anyone have a paper or other references on Bayesian group-Lasso for probit/logit model or GLM (generalized linear models) in general? I could not find any paper that explicitly deals with this.